# Docker can't connect to container on bridge interface

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to setup a compose file to support a legacy application. Said legacy app needs to connect to up to 3 DBs (MySQL). The problem is I can't change the port specification. I mean, I probably could, but we want to containerize everything without having to change any code.

when I run docker inspect on one of my containers I get:

```
 "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
```

which is good. But when I attempt to connect from my MAC
I get timeout. In the past, I have had to make a network alias like such:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24
```

But, it doesn't seem to help

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
```

mac:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin wa-cbongiorno-mba.local 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Here is the compose file I am working with:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db1:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    volumes:
      - ./Schema/db1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
  db2:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - 3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    volumes:
      - ./Schema/db2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Comment: You say "In the past", do you mean you had this working at one point or has this never worked?

Comment: You are using docker for mac or docker toolbox?

Comment: @AndyShinn I have been able to connect to containers on their IPs in the past of my career but not on this project

Comment: @TarunLalwani Docker for mac

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers), this is not possible as of now on mac

### Known Limitations, Use Cases, and Workarounds

Following is a summary of current limitations on the Docker for Mac networking stack, along with some ideas for workarounds.

#### There is no docker0 bridge on macOS

Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker for Mac, you cannot see a docker0 interface in macOS. This interface is actually within HyperKit.

#### I cannot ping my containers

Unfortunately, due to limitations in macOS, we’re unable to route traffic to containers, and from containers back to the host.

#### Per-container IP addressing is not possible

The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host.

#### Use cases and workarounds

There are two scenarios that the above limitations will affect:

### I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST

The Mac has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 17.06 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special Mac-only DNS name docker.for.mac.localhost which will resolve to the internal IP address used by the host.

### I WANT TO CONNECT TO A CONTAINER FROM THE MAC

Port forwarding works for localhost; --publish, -p, or -P all work. Ports exposed from Linux are forwarded to the Mac.

Our current recommendation is to publish a port, or to connect from another container. Note that this is what you have to do even on Linux if the container is on an overlay network, not a bridge network, as these are not routed.

Comment: I know for a fact I was able to do this in the past. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Ugh this is annoying - means I can't use Traefik on Mac.

Comment: `The docker (Linux) bridge network is not reachable from the macOS host.` What does this mean? you can't connect to docker on linux from docker on macOS ?